# Geojson style based on property value using leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a geojson file, I am trying to assign a color to property values. when I used randomly generated color function it worked. but when I am using below code does not assign colors.
Thank you for helping me.

```
function getColor(d) {
    return d == 11.70   ? 'red' :
           d == 13.92   ? 'green' :
           d == 14.10   ? 'yellow' :
           d == 11.51   ? 'gray' :
           d == 14.55   ? 'blue' :
           d == 14.79   ? 'magenta' :
           d == 45.60   ? 'orange' :
           d == 11.39   ? 'brown' :
           d == 13.56   ? 'pink' :
           d == 12.53   ? 'darkblue' :
                          '#00000';
            }

function style(feature) {
    return {
        fillColor: getColor(),
        weight: 2,
        fillOpacity: 1
      };
    }
var isobandsLayer = L.geoJSON(isobands,{
style:style
}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an argument to the function `getColor(d)`:

```
function style(feature) {
    return {
        fillColor: getColor(feature.propertes.YOUR_COLOR_D_VALUE),
        weight: 2,
        fillOpacity: 1
      };
    }
```

Comment: I did but no use

Answer (score 0):

Replace `fillColor: getColor(),` with `color: getColor(),`